# Can I make a MongoDB field value change depending on other values?

Tags: database, mongodb

As an example, here is something similar to what will be in my database:

```
"name": "Task A",
"completed": false,
"no_of_items": placeholder1
"no_completed_items": placeholder2
"items": {"name": "Task A1",
    "completed": false,
    "no_of_items": placeholder1
    "no_completed_items": placeholder2
    "items": {placeholder3}
    },
    "name": "Task A2",
    "completed": false,
    "no_of_items": placeholder1
    "no_completed_items": placeholder2
    "items": {placeholder3}
```

With that in mind, what I would like is:

- placeholder1 to be the number of items in the items field (is there a way to get the length perhaps?).
- placeholder2 to be the number of items in the items field where completed is true.
- 'completed' to be changed from false to true when no_completed_items equals no_of_items

placeholder3 is just there because this will be multiple levels deep, but shouldn't affect our example. At a certain depth, objects will no longer have multiple items, and users will check off these bottom-level tasks. When they complete all of the tasks, I would like the level above to reflect that 'completed' is now true (based on the no_completed_items being the same as no_of_items, as these could change in the future).

Comment: [collection.watch()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) could be a possible solution (replica sets only)